# Ajax response blocks click event

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, browser

This issue is really bumping my head. I have a page with multiple input fields (you can call it a form). 
Some fields trigger a ajax-call to perform serside form validation on the input field. The page has two buttons. The buttons will trigger a ajax call to submit the page (not submit buttons) to do somethinf with the data.

Now the issue is, when having focus on a field with a submit and i click on the button, the click on the buttons is being ignored. But not only on the button. I have tried to add a listeners to the body to handle click, but even the click is not being logged.

I found something on the internet that browsers prevent click actions when a submit/post in a form is done. So I removed the form-tags. At first i thought it worked, but it didn't.

When I throtle the page, I can get a working page. What I see is happneing is that when the first ajax call has no repsonse yet, click are handled and therefore the button can be clicked, but when the ajax-call is finished click are ignored (at a very high level, the browser does not even dispatches the click event).

Is anyone familiar with this browser bahavior? And can that somebody tell me how  to avoid this?

EDIT:

This works:

Without throttling 
Focus in submit field (submits on blur)
Mousedown on button (field is submitting)
Mouseup on button after a second or two (click of the button is handled)

This does not work:
Focus in submit field (submits on blur)
Mousedown on button (field is submitting)
Mouseup on button instantly, like a click (click (of the button) is not handled)

Reproduction:

```
<h3>Tasks</h3>

<form data-bind="submit: addTask">
    Add task: <input data-bind="value: newTaskText" placeholder="" />
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>

<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length > 0">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
        <input data-bind="value: title, disable: isDone" />
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeTask">Delete</a>
    </li> 
</ul>

You have <b data-bind="text: incompleteTasks().length">&nbsp;</b> incomplete task(s)
<span data-bind="visible: incompleteTasks().length == 0"> - it's beer time!</span>

<button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>


function Task(data) {
    this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
    this.isDone = ko.observable(data.isDone);
}

function TaskListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.newTaskText = ko.observable();
    self.incompleteTasks = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.tasks(), function(task) { return !task.isDone() && !task._destroy });
    });

    self.newTaskText.subscribe(function(){
      console.log('submit');
        self.addTask();
    });

    // Operations
    self.addTask = function() {
        self.tasks.push(new Task({ title: this.newTaskText() }));
        self.newTaskText("");
    };
    self.removeTask = function(task) { self.tasks.destroy(task) };
    self.save = function() {
        $.ajax("/echo/json/", {
            data: {
                json: ko.toJSON({ tasks: self.tasks }),
                delay: 0
            },
            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(result) { console.log(); }
        });
    };


}

ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fervanrijswijk/cr22jmxh/

EDIT:
Seems not te be a good reproduction path

Comment: after which event the validations are fired?

Comment: an input field can sub mit information to validatie the specific field. A click on the button will validate the page again. 
It not so much that validations are triggered, but more that a ajx request is called. This ajax request gives new json for the page to render (with knockout)

Comment: Do you need to prevent the default event of the buttons and then do your ajax call?

Comment: I assume, you are using knockout to bind for the click events on the buttons. If so (or anyways), I would suggest you to look at the button element and try to see if the click event is registered on it the moment you are clicking, because it might happen that after you are getting the data back from the ajax request and binding is done with the new json data, the event is not registered..

Comment: @matthew - prevent default is not used in the code

Comment: @gkb - My thoughts exactly, but I have set jquery click event bind to body aswell. This click is also not being executed.